# What is the execution sequence (which after which) among web.php, LoginController.php and AdminMiddleWare.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I login with user type 'admin' then how does the code sequence will be executed? In which states Admin Middleware works or Login Controller or Routes. And redirectTo() function of Login Controller returns 'dashboard' or 'home' to where. Please helps me in details

**web.php or route**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard',function(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

**LoginController.php**

```
protected function redirectTo(){
    if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin'){
        return 'dashboard';
    }
    else{
        return 'home';
    }
}
```

**AdminMiddleware.php**

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After user login: (in case of `usertype == admin`)

1- The function of `redirectTo()` in `LoginController.php` will be executed.

2- The logged in user will be checked by the `AdminMiddleware`.

3- The user will reach the route `admin.dashboard` function, according to the result of the `AdminMiddleware`.

After user login: (in case of `usertype != admin`)

1- The function of `redirectTo()` in `LoginController.php` will be executed.

2- The user will reach the route `home` function, according to the result of the `LoginController.php`.

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot. But I want to clear a little bit. If after login: (usertype == admin) and LoginController redirect to AdminMiddleware then why 'non admin' user not to redirect to AdminMiddleware. Because in redirectTo() function there is no terms or hints of AdminMiddleware.

Comment: Non admin users are redirected earlier (in else statement) in `LoginController.php` to a route that has no `AdminMiddleware` attached to it.